# Professor Halfbrain's quadrilateral theorem

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Professor Halfbrain has recently made a fascinating discovery on quadrilaterals in the plane.

> **Halfbrain's quadrilateral theorem:**
>   Let $ABCD$ be a plane quadrilateral that possesses an incircle and a circumcircle.
>   If the center of the incircle coincides with the center of the circumcircle, then $ABCD$ is a square.

Question: Is this theorem indeed true, or has the professor once again made one of his mathematical blunders?

Comment: Today I learned what a [bicentric quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_quadrilateral#Distance_between_the_incenter_and_circumcenter) is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is

> true

Proof:

> Let's first draw the concentric incircle and circumcircle. We draw the quadrilateral starting with a vertex on the outer circle and proceeding clockwise. The edge leaving that vertex must be tangent to the inner circle and so is forced. 
>
>  The next vertex is where this line intersects the outer circle. Now, we're in the same situation as before, but rotated. So, the resulting shape must be rotationally-symmetric (edge-transitive). 
>
>  If it returns to the initial vertex without crossing itself, it must be a regular polygon. If it has four edges, it's a square.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem is...

> ... not true. There are an infinite number of **concave** quadrangles which also bicentric with a incentre-circumcentre distance of zero, each one associated with a specific out-radius:in-radius ratio $R/r$, where $R/r < \sqrt{2}$. According to [Fuss' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_quadrilateral#Fuss.27_theorem), only in the special case where $R/r = \sqrt{2}$ does a square solution appear.

Proof:

> To construct a concave solution, within a given circle, draw two arbitrary chords $AB$ and $AD$ from $A$, such that $\angle BAD < 60^{\circ}$. Then, draw the incircle such that the chords $AB$ and $AD$ are both tangent to the incircle. Finally, choose a point $C$ on the incircle to complete the quadrangle $ABCD$.

Comment: Does a concave quadrilateral have a circumcircle? I understand that to mean that all four points lie on that circle, i.e. it is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: By the way, your construction didn't work for me. Also, Fuss theorem applies to any bicentric quad. If you plus $d=0$ in it, You get $R/r= \sqrt{2}$ which only holds for a square.

Comment: Yes, Fuss' Theorem only applies to simple convex quadrilaterals. For the concave case, as xnor has noitced, I took the liberty to generalize the incircle and circumcircle to the maximum inscriptable circle and the minimum bounded circle, respectively (otherwise both are hilariously undefined for the concave polygon).